# How to count rows created before the current row grouped by the current category level

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a table with three columns. First is a unique id, second is a date or a timestamp and third is a group or category. I want to transform this such that I get the counts of all ids created before the current date and belonging to the current category. (Attached sample before and after tables)

This is query I wrote:

```
select 
t1.group, t1.date, count(*) 
from oldtable t1
left join oldtable t2 on t2.group=t1.group
where t1.date>t2.date
group by t1.group, t1.date
order by t1.date, t1.group
;
```

The query seems to work. But the actual dataset has almost a million rows and I want to know if there's a better and faster way of doing this.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6S1W.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRwR0.png)

Comment: Note: `date` is a bad name for a column. `group` is also a bad name for a column.

Comment: I know. This is just an example. I'm sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: It is not confusing *to me*. But it is bad style (IMHO), and it *could* (in the future) confuse tools and middleware. Just avoid it, and use other (more descriptive ...) names.

Comment: I understand. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: `rank() over (partition by grp order by dt) - 1`

Comment: So, you want a cumulative count? (number of observations *before* a certain date, per group?

Comment: Yes. I think the query I wrote works but it seems slow and inefficient.

Comment: @shawnt00 Can you explain the code? It seems to work on a sample dataset.

Comment: It counts off the rows in the partition by order of date. I have no idea of you can have ties by date. Row_number is similar.

Comment: I think there are multiple rows with same date in the original dataset.

Comment: Try both and see which matches what you need. Add a second ordering column if necessary.

Comment: If the id column is not unique per row, is it possible to adjust the query so that we can count unique ids before a certain date per group

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Count distinct does get more complicated though.

Comment: Looks like it. I tried to use Count(Distinct id) over (...), but apparently distinct is not supported in window functions. I'm trying to find an alternative solution online.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=99a1a5ec1fd0fca06754758b01810741